# System.xml showing 404 error

Tags: admin, system.xml

Below is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <NameSpace_ModuleName>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
       </NameSpace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Below is my `adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <mymodulename>
                                    <title>Customer Config</title>
                                    <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                                </mymodulename>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Below is my `system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <mymodule translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Customer Config</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>Customer Configuration</label>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enable My Module</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </mymodule >
    </sections>
</config>
```

I can see the section under `Customer Tab`, but when I click on it, it gives me `404 Not found` error

My `system.log` is empty and shows nothing.

Please help to resolve.

Comment: Did you logout and relogin in the backend?

Comment: Yes. Cleared cache too. When I put `if(!$xml){ Mage::log($string); } ` in my `Config.php (located at /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php) and line 510`, it prints `2014-08-05T12:25:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): <config/>` in `system.log`

Comment: Did you add the ACL for your section in `adminhtml.xml` or `config.xml`?

Comment: Yes, pls check the updated question.

Comment: Do you check with an administrator account? Check the user roles in the admin and check if the new right is activated for your user roole.

Comment: but your adminhtml.xml contains only the acl for the menu item. You need one for the system section. take this file as example `/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/adminhtml.xml`. See the `<system>` tag

Comment: No its for section as well. Pls see the xml code once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `adminhtml.xml` might be missing a couple tags.  When adding new configuration areas, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mymodule>
                                        <title>Config Tag Name Goes Here</title>
                                    </mymodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

I think you're missing the `system > children > config > children` part.  Try adding that and it should work.  (You may need to log out and log back in).

Comment: Did you see my updated `adminhtml.xml` ?

Comment: No, I didn't.  You're getting closer!  It looks like you just need to rename `<section_name>` to `<mymodule>` (it should match what you have in `system.xml` under `config > sections`

Comment: yes, its the same. Section name is same as module name.

Comment: Your recent edit has two `<mymodulename>`s.  The second one should be a closing tag: `</mymodulename>`.  Does that fix things for you?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Still same error